# Tricking feedback of a buck converter

Tags: buck, feedback, compensation

I need to trick the buck converter feedback. The converter that I am going to use is TPS40192DRCT.

Instead of the regular resistor divider, I want to feed there voltage proportional to current somewhere else. So when somewhere the current rises, this voltage would go lower and make the converter increase the duty cycle. This will reduce the current I am measuring there.

I am not sure what to do with the compensation though. Can i simply connect the network to the GND instead the feedback?

[image]

Comment: Increasing duty cycle would increase the current! Sounds like you want constant current as opposed to constant voltage. Yes, you can do as you propose. The devil is in the details though.

Comment: No, no. It will take current away from that other place, sort of a switching bypass

Comment: Read the last two sentences.

Comment: I have, thank you

Comment: Its just a test or do you have any spec ? Do you want to increase the voltage output or current output?

Comment: It's a prototype. Voltage is set elsewhere, this circuit only should regulate current.

Comment: Any delay you introduce into the loop may affect stability. Follow Tim's recommendation not just to save components, but also to save delay and phase shift.

Answer (score 1):

It will work in principle, but your polarity is inverted.

When FB rises, the converter will tend to *reduce* the duty cycle (in order to regulate FB at the required regulation point). Your as-drawn circuit has an inversion.

If you make your 1st amplifier into a fixed-gain difference amplifier with an offset, you should be able to set it to generate the 591 mV FV reference at your desired current.

Your compensation could be quite difficult because of the dynamics of what generates or affects the current you are sensing.

Comment: Thank you. The dynamics in principle is very slow and adjustable - I don't hope to somply get it right. The polarity will be such that higher current will push the feedback lower, making the controller increase the duty cycle.

Comment: So, higher current is the consequence of a higher duty cycle.  And you're saying that this consequence of a higher duty cycle will push the duty cycle even _higher_.  That's positive feedback, which is only good if you want the thing to tend to latch in a high current or low current state.

Comment: I don't measure this converter current. It's the sum of the converter and some other current that is constant.

Answer (score 1):

The part of your circuit that I've drawn a red trapezoid around is already there inside the TPS40192.  Look at the functional block diagram in the datasheet -- the FB pin goes into an inverting input of an op-amp, there's an internal reference on that amplifier's non-inverting input, and the amplifier's output goes to the chip's "COMP" pin.

For example, the compensation network that they show is the classic feedback network for an op-amp proportional-integral stage.

As long as you can live with their reference voltage, you don't need to add an op-amp, with its delay and bandwidth limitations.

[image]

Comment: It was thinking I would need an integrator stage. But I will prepare a bypass, thank you.

Comment: Their compensation network provides proportional-integral action, with a lead-lag filter between Vout and the feedback pin.

Comment: Yes, but then the output capacitor is taken out of the feedback loop. Frankly i don't know what will be the effect.

Comment: Presumably you need to use compensation that's appropriate for whatever you're doing (you never said where your current is coming _from_).  If you want info on _that_ you should probably start a new question.